# Using Virtual Channel on a 64-bit Client

Tags: .net, 64-bit, terminal-services, virtual-channel

I'm trying to write a Terminal Services add-in with .Net (VB or C#) and am following this project on Code Project:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/TSAddinInCS.aspx

However, when trying to run this on a 64 bit Windows 7 OS, it doesn't run at all.  The client portion never gets launched.  Has anyone run into this and found a way to make this work?

Comment: You can try using `UnmanagedExports` extension for VS2013 that allows `DllExport` for x64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up going with [Remote Executer For Terminal Server](http://www.mqtechnologies.com/en/Home.aspx) to handle this.

We had to talk to the developer and have him build a 64-bit client but he did that and now we're using this solution.  It's working very well, just thought I'd post an update for any future searches.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but in case someone is still using the CP example like I did: the ExportDll tool from the CP example is an old version, the newer version at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9150/Execute-a-function-in-any-Win-DLL-Reflection-in has a switch "/x64" to rebuild the IL into 64-bit assembly, which is required to work with x64 mstsc.exe